# rabbitmq connection using pika

Tags: python, python-2.7, ssl, rabbitmq

I configured RabbitMQ server with SSL and I am using Python 2.7.8 with pika to connect to it with no problem. I configured the server to take client certificate and it must verify in order to connect.

But when I switch to Python 2.7.11 in another project and using exactly the same code and same client side certificate and same pika version, the RabbitMQ server is shutting the connection down.

Python exception:

```
 File "..\lib\site-packages\pika\adapters\blocking_connection.py", line 339, in __init__
    self._process_io_for_connection_setup()
  File "..\lib\site-packages\pika\adapters\blocking_connection.py", line 374, in _process_io_for_connection_setup
    self._open_error_result.is_ready)
  File "..\lib\site-packages\pika\adapters\blocking_connection.py", line 395, in _flush_output
    raise exceptions.ConnectionClosed()
pika.exceptions.ConnectionClosed
```

RabbitMQ server log:

```
error on AMQP connection <0.966.0>: {ssl_upgrade_failure,
                                     {{function_clause,
                                       [{tls_v1,enum_to_oid,
                                         [28],
                                         [{file,"tls_v1.erl"},{line,404}]},
                                        {ssl_handshake,
                                         '-dec_hello_extensions/2-blc$^1/1-0-',
                                         1,
                                         [{file,"ssl_handshake.erl"},
                                          {line,1653}]},
                                        {ssl_handshake,
                                         '-dec_hello_extensions/2-blc$^1/1-0-',
                                         1,
                                         [{file,"ssl_handshake.erl"},
                                          {line,1653}]},
                                        {ssl_handshake,dec_hello_extensions,
                                         2,
                                         [{file,"ssl_handshake.erl"},
                                          {line,1653}]},
                                        {tls_handshake,decode_handshake,3,
                                         [{file,"tls_handshake.erl"},
                                          {line,182}]},
                                        {tls_handshake,get_tls_handshake_aux,
                                         3,
                                         [{file,"tls_handshake.erl"},
                                          {line,153}]},
                                        {tls_connection,next_state,4,
                                         [{file,"tls_connection.erl"},
                                          {line,454}]},
                                        {gen_fsm,handle_msg,7,
                                         [{file,"gen_fsm.erl"},{line,505}]}]},
                                      {gen_fsm,sync_send_all_state_event,
                                       [<0.967.0>,{start,5000},infinity]}}} (unknown POSIX error)
```

The RabbitMQ server's domain name is "rabbit.test.com". The CN for the server cert and client cert are exactly the same with the domain name.

Any idea why it works on Python 2.7.8 but not Python 2.7.11?

Comment: The SSL implementation was updated for Python 2.7.9, guessing that it's causing what ever error you are experiencing. https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0466/

Comment: @eandersson Yes, I know that there are changes to SSL in 2.7.9. I feel that I have done everything right, thought. Given the handshake process I feel like it's client side cert not being trusted by the server, but I do not know why.

Comment: @ShengcongWang any progress since 2014? I think I'm facing simliar problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64952005/pika-rabbitmq-docker-with-tls-gen-connection-reset-no-logs