# pika rabbitmq docker with tls-gen connection reset, no logs

Tags: docker, rabbitmq, tls1.2, pika

I've configured a docker w rabbitmq, copied the certs from [tls-gen](https://github.com/michaelklishin/tls-gen) there, stop/started and I can only get the connection established and a server reset right after sending a TLS Client Hello. No useful message from ssl. Logs all empty. Troubleshoot TLS guide didn't help. Thanks for any help.

```
docker run -d -it --hostname=[REDACTED] -e RABBITMQ_LOGS=/var/log/rabbitmq/ -e RABBITMQ_SASL_LOGS=/var/log/rabbitmq/ -e RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER=[REDACTED] -e RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS=[REDACTED] --name rabbitmq1 -p [REDACTED]:5672 -p [REDACTED]:15672 -v /scratch/databases/rabbitmq/var/lib/rabbitmq:/var/lib/rabbitmq rabbitmq:3-management


docker cp tls-gen/basic/result/ca_certificate.pem rabbitmq1:/etc/rabbitmq/
docker cp tls-gen/basic/result/server_key.pem rabbitmq1:/etc/rabbitmq/
docker cp tls-gen/basic/result/server_certificate.pem rabbitmq1:/etc/rabbitmq/
docker exec -it rabbitmq1 /bin/bash -c "cd /etc/rabbitmq;chown rabbitmq:rabbitmq *.pem"
docker cp rabbitmq.conf rabbitmq1:/etc/rabbitmq/
docker exec -it rabbitmq1 /bin/bash -c "cd /etc/rabbitmq;chown rabbitmq:rabbitmq rabbitmq.conf"
```

I was sure to restart the container so the changes were applied. Also double checked cert permissions.

`docker:/etc/rabbitmq/`

```
-rw-rw-r--. 1 rabbitmq rabbitmq 1.2K Nov 22 02:29 ca_certificate.pem
drwxrwxrwx. 1 rabbitmq rabbitmq   61 Nov  6 01:51 conf.d
-rw-r--r--. 1 root     root       71 Nov 22 07:34 enabled_plugins
-rw-r--r--. 1 rabbitmq rabbitmq  578 Nov 22 07:34 rabbitmq.conf
-rw-rw-r--. 1 rabbitmq rabbitmq 1.3K Nov 22 02:29 server_certificate.pem
-rw-------. 1 rabbitmq rabbitmq 1.9K Nov 22 02:29 server_key.pem
```

Redirected logs here knowing that the container start env variables should overide. Either way, logs seemed empty.

`/etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.conf`

```
loopback_users.guest = false
# listeners.tcp.default = 5672
management.tcp.port = 15672

listeners.tcp = none

listeners.ssl.default = 5671

ssl_options.cacertfile = /etc/rabbitmq/ca_certificate.pem
ssl_options.certfile   = /etc/rabbitmq/server_certificate.pem
ssl_options.keyfile    = /etc/rabbitmq/server_key.pem
ssl_options.verify     = verify_peer
ssl_options.fail_if_no_peer_cert = false
ssl_options.password   = [REDACTED]
log.dir = /tmp/
log.file = r.log
log.file.level = debug
```

Tried multiple configurations for context.options to no avail.

`receive.py (python)`

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import ssl, pika, sys, os
import traceback
from pika.credentials import ExternalCredentials

def main():
    connection = None
    credentials = pika.PlainCredentials('[REDACTED]', '[REDACTED]')

    context = ssl.create_default_context(cafile="tls-gen/basic/result/ca_certificate.pem")
    context.load_cert_chain("tls-gen/basic/result/client_certificate.pem", "tls-gen/basic/result/client_key.pem")
    #context.options = dict(ssl_version=ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1, cert_reqs=ssl.CERT_REQUIRED)
    ssl_options = pika.SSLOptions(context, "[REDACTED]")
    #ssl_options = pika.SSLOptions(ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLS_CLIENT), "local")
    #ssl_options = pika.SSLOptions(ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLS_SERVER), "localhost")
    #ssl_options = ssl_options | pika.SSLOptions(ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2), "[REDACTED]")
    try:
      connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters(host='[REDACTED]',
        port=[REDACTED], 
        virtual_host='/',
        ssl_options = ssl_options)),
        credentials=credentials))
        #credentials=ExternalCredentials()))
    except Exception as e:
      exc_type, _, exc_tb = sys.exc_info()
      fname = os.path.split(exc_tb.tb_frame.f_code.co_filename)[1]
      print("receive: ({0}) {1} {2} {3}".format(str(e), exc_type, fname, exc_tb.tb_lineno))
      traceback.print_exc()
      sys.exit(1)
    channel = connection.channel()

    channel.queue_declare(queue='hello')

    def callback(ch, method, properties, body):
        print(" [x] Received %r" % body)

    channel.basic_consume(queue='hello', on_message_callback=callback, auto_ack=True)

    print(' [*] Waiting for messages. To exit press CTRL+C')
    channel.start_consuming()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        main()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print('Interrupted')
        try:
            sys.exit(0)
        except SystemExit:
            os._exit(0)
```

A wrong PEM password here generates a very different message, I'm sure I'm using the right one.

`python3 receive.py`

```
Enter PEM pass phrase:
receive: ([Errno 104] Connection reset by peer) <class 'ConnectionResetError'> receive.py 18
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "receive.py", line 18, in main
    connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters(host='[REDACTED]',
  File "[REDACTED]/rabbitmq/pika/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pika/adapters/blocking_connection.py", line 359, in __init__
    self._impl = self._create_connection(parameters, _impl_class)
  File "[REDACTED]/rabbitmq/pika/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pika/adapters/blocking_connection.py", line 450, in _create_connection
    raise self._reap_last_connection_workflow_error(error)
  File "[REDACTED]/rabbitmq/pika/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pika/adapters/utils/io_services_utils.py", line 636, in _do_ssl_handshake
    self._sock.do_handshake()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/ssl.py", line 1309, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ConnectionResetError: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer
```

It looks like openssl likes the connection.

`openssl s_client -connect localhost:5671`

```
CONNECTED(00000003)
Can't use SSL_get_servername
depth=1 CN = TLSGenSelfSignedtRootCA, L = $$$$
verify error:num=19:self signed certificate in certificate chain
verify return:1
depth=0 CN = [REDACTED], O = server
verify return:1
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:CN = [REDACTED], O = server
   i:CN = TLSGenSelfSignedtRootCA, L = $$$$
 1 s:CN = TLSGenSelfSignedtRootCA, L = $$$$
   i:CN = TLSGenSelfSignedtRootCA, L = $$$$
---
Server certificate
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
[REDACTED]
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
subject=CN = [REDACTED], O = server

issuer=CN = TLSGenSelfSignedtRootCA, L = $$$$

---
Acceptable client certificate CA names
CN = TLSGenSelfSignedtRootCA, L = $$$$
Client Certificate Types: ECDSA sign, RSA sign, DSA sign
Requested Signature Algorithms: ECDSA+SHA512:RSA+SHA512:ECDSA+SHA384:RSA+SHA384:ECDSA+SHA256:RSA+SHA256:ECDSA+SHA224:RSA+SHA224:ECDSA+SHA1:RSA+SHA1:DSA+SHA1
Shared Requested Signature Algorithms: ECDSA+SHA512:RSA+SHA512:ECDSA+SHA384:RSA+SHA384:ECDSA+SHA256:RSA+SHA256:ECDSA+SHA224:RSA+SHA224:ECDSA+SHA1:RSA+SHA1:DSA+SHA1
Peer signing digest: SHA256
Peer signature type: RSA
Server Temp Key: ECDH, P-256, 256 bits
---
SSL handshake has read 2338 bytes and written 431 bytes
Verification error: self signed certificate in certificate chain
---
New, TLSv1.2, Cipher is ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
Server public key is 2048 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.2
    Cipher    : ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
    Session-ID: [REDACTED]
    Session-ID-ctx: 
    Master-Key: [REDACTED]
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    Start Time: 1606031943
    Timeout   : 7200 (sec)
    Verify return code: 19 (self signed certificate in certificate chain)
    Extended master secret: no
---
closed
```

Answer (score 0):

here the steps I took to fix this:

1. Get rid of the docker and install a local rabbitmq on mac for debugging this configuration. For some reason, the rabbitmq docker wasn't logging anything;
2. I've added a real valid letsencrypt certificate to the server;
3. first error I saw in the client after that was the following:
   `ssl.SSLError: [SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_UNKNOWN_CA] tlsv1 alert unknown ca (_ssl.c:1076)` 
   This is because verify_peer is enabled, in that case we needed to bundle the ca_certificate.pem from tls-gen/basic/result/ca_certificate.pem to the chain.pem
   `cat ../tls-gen/basic/result/ca_certificate.pem chain.pem > chain_bundle.pem`

rabbitmq.conf

```
...
ssl_options.cacertfile = /usr/local/etc/rabbitmq/chain_bundle.pem # <- bundled w self signed cert
ssl_options.certfile   = /usr/local/etc/rabbitmq/cert.pem
ssl_options.keyfile    = /usr/local/etc/rabbitmq/privkey.pem
...
```

1. after that, a different error on pika showed:
   `ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1076)`
   That's because pika didn't like `tls-gen/basic/result/ca_certificate.pem`, instead, I used `venv//lib/python3.7/site-packages/certifi/cacert.pem` after installing `pip install certifi`.
2. Later on, I bundled `tls-gen/basic/result/ca_certificate.pem` +  `venv//lib/python3.7/site-packages/certifi/cacert.pem`, and added a password to context.load_cert_chain

Wireshark shows messages fully encrypted, now I just need to deploy.

EDIT:
I was able to run it via docker after re-trying the configuration that worked:

```
#/bin/bash

docker run -d -it --hostname=\
    -e RABBITMQ_LOGS=/tmp/log\
    -e RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER=\
    -e RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS=\
    -e RABBITMQ_SSL_CACERTFILE=/cert/chain_bundle2.pem \
    -e RABBITMQ_SSL_CERTFILE=/cert/cert.pem\
    -e RABBITMQ_SSL_KEYFILE=/cert/privkey.pem\
    -e RABBITMQ_SSL_FAIL_IF_NO_PEER_CERT=true\
    -e RABBITMQ_SSL_VERIFY=verify_peer\
    --name rabbitmq1-verifypeer -p ... :5671 -p ... :15672\
    -v ... /rabbitmq/var/log:/tmp/log\
        -v ... /rabbitmq/var/lib/rabbitmq:/var/lib/rabbitmq\
        -v ... /cert/:/cert/ rabbitmq:3.8.9-management
```